# Unable to find Java & Android SDK - Google Play Services in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I downloaded unity package for google play services. After installing the package I opened up the window for Android configuration but after putting in the Resource definition, I get several errors: that Java and Android SDK is missing and that XML resource is not correct. I have the latest Unity version and when installing, it also installed Java and Android automatically, I didn't need to download any JDKs from java and android websites.

What am I missing??

[image]

Comment: did you try going to `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `External Tools` and search/configure the JDK?

Comment: @derHugo No. Do I need to manually install JDK, SDK and everything else?

Comment: I thought you said it was installed automatically. Find it on your PC ... `Unity installs Android SDK & NDK tools respectively in the SDK and NDK folders under /Unity/Hub/Editor/[EditorVersion]/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/.` (from [Android environment setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html))

Comment: In this case, first you should set up the environment variable path . This link [https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml]walks you through how to do it. 
Still, if you find any errors let me know. I would love to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "**Edit**" -> "**Preferences**" -> "**External Tools**" and scroll down to Android, there's a text field to enter the path to your SDK.  There's also a "**Download**" button next to the field that will take you directly to the download location.  I recommend getting all 3 (SDK, JDK, NDK).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs sometimes even you already locate java sdk, just go to Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver on unity then click Resolve. Just click OK when finished now you can build apk/app bundle without java sdk locate error.